# JasperReports net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Byte data not found at : reports/logo.png

Tags: java, scala, sbt

現在帳票をpdf出力する処理を作っているのですが、以下の処理になります。

```
val path: String = File.createTempFile("tmp", "report.pdf").getAbsolutePath
//pdfを作成
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(
  JasperFillManager.fillReport(
    JasperCompileManager.compileReport("conf/report.jrxml"),
    Map("userName" -> this.userName)
  ),path)
```

開発環境ですと正常に動きますが、
sbt-assemblyでjarファイルにして起動すると、
以下のログで処理が終わらなくなります

```
[debug] - org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.sax - endPrefixMapping()
[debug] - org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.sax - endPrefixMapping(xsi)
[debug] - org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.sax - endDocument()
[debug] - net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseReportFiller - Fill 1: created for report
[debug] - net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseReportFiller - created delayed actions 1 for filler 1
```

色々探しまして、font云々の情報が多かったのですが、試しに白紙になるようなjrxmlファイルを作成しましたが、結果は変わりませんでした。

環境
Linux
Scala 2.11.7
java 1.8.0_51
jasperreports 6.1.1

よろしくお願いします。

追記:
色々やっていき、エラーメッセージが表示されました。

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Byte data not found at : reports/logo.png
```

どこを指定すればよいのか分かりません...
sbt-assemblyでjarファイル化するとパスが違っていくるようで、上記のエラーが出ます。よろしくおねがいします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

解決しましたので、共有させて頂きます。

sbt-assembly によりjarファイル化され、内部に配置されている画像がパスで取得できず、上記のエラーになっていました。
InputStreamでのアクセスは可能なようなので、fillReport時に

```
new java.util.HashMap[String, java.lang.Object](Map(
    "logo" -> JRLoader.getLocationInputStream("reports/logo.png")
))
```

JRLoader.getLocationInputStreamでInputStream型で画像パスを取得し、内部でパラメータ定義すれば表示できました。